# I am having problems setting the value of a class based on a scope variable?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code:

```
xx {{ state.params.contentTitle }} xx
yy {{ $state.params.contentTitle }} yy
<a class="dw" 
   data-ng-class="{ current: state.params.contentTitle.includes('overview2') }"
   href="/home/overview2"><span>Overview2</span>
</a>
```

When I look at my browser I see:

```
xx overview2 xx yy overview2 yy
```

When I look at the HTML with the chrome debugger I cannot see any mention of the class being set to current.

Here is what I see in the debugger:

```
<a class="dw" data-ng-class="{ current: state.params.contentTitle.includes('overview2') }" href="/home/overview2"><span>Overview2</span>
                    </a>
```

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: contentTitle is a string. What does the function `includes` do? Where is it defined.

Comment: Actually I'm sorry but I don't know. This is just standard javascript. I looked it up and also was not sure about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you

```
    <a class="dw" data-ng-class="{ current: state.params.contentTitle=='overview2' }" href="/home/overview2">
         <span>Overview2</span>
   </a>
```

Basically remove the `includes` function you were using.